# Uniformly distribute elements

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I need to calculate the position of the elements with variable width and height within an element with a fixed width.
It's like the Pinterest board, but with variable element width (it's not determined by block's content, in my case there's two sizes of the block - 170x140 or 140x170), so i cannot use columns.

[Here's the visual example of the desired result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qhan08mmmc9lqvp/distribute.jpg?m)

Floating is not an option as it produces gaps that are too large.
display:inline and display:inline-block also does not produce the required result.

It seems like there's a mathematical algorithm, how each box position is calculated?

Calculations will be done in Javascript.

Comment: That'strange, since display: inline should do exactly what you need. Could you post a sample code with exact elements in question?

Comment: I cannot use inline because i need each block to have it's own width and height. In my case, each block need to be 170x140 or 140x170 px.

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) might help, if you'd care to give it a look. (You'd be able to float everything.)

Comment: Woah, that seems exactly what i need. Will take a look if can get plain algorightm out of that.

Comment: Link to the visual example is not working, anymore.